# R Need to compare rows in R based on an ID and a non- Unique second column distribution of a time shift

Tags: r

I need to compare the first and last value (take the difference) . I tried lagging the user (C/A)  column. Picture person 1 as C and person 2 as A.

The issue is that there are distinct periods from C to C to C etc where there is no upper limit, so I need something flexible enough. For 2 periods I can just lug sequence and join on that , but that is simply a special case and doesn't help me at all. What I need to determine is the distribution of the time shift from the first C to the last C , for each period, so each ID may have multiple C->C-> C -> etc  shifts, So I cannot create a unique identifier by concatenating ID and Sequence and user to group by which would have been great if each period of Cs had a unique id as well. There is a Dummy for when C=C to help identify. If I can sum by the difference by dummy for each period of Cs I can get what I need too. For example below the 17+15 in rows 2 and 3 = the time difference for the C-C-C period, I need that for all occurrences.

Here is an example of the data so far:

Data:

```
 ID    Sequen_num    user      time_shift  userlag1  time_shift2  difference    Dummy(user= C userlag1=C )  

1         1             A           1           C            15        14            0  
1         2             C          15           C            32        17            1  
1         3             C          32           C            47        15            1  
1         4             C          47           A            65        18            0
1         5             A          65           C            80        15            0
1         6             C          80           C            110       30            1
1         7             C          110          A            120       10            0
1         8             A          120
```

If I had something like this it would be amazingly easy(basically a way to identify each block within each ID) :

```
  ID    Sequen_num        user block   user      time_shift  userlag1  time_shift2  difference    Dummy(user= C userlag1=C )  

1         1                1          A           1           C            15        14            0  
1         2                2          C          15           C            32        17            1  
1         3                2          C          32           C            47        15            1  
1         4                2          C          47           A            65        18            0
1         5                3          A          65           C            80        15            0
1         6                4          C          80           C            110       30            1
1         7                4          C          110          A            120       10            0
1         8                5          A          120
```

Comment: indent the table lines by 4 spaces

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thanks for that. I have been using Stackexchange and overflow for a long time for referencing, but have never posted. I have been searching all day and cannot find anything on this issue specifically . I am used to things like a unique ID for each cluster for the "C-C-C" which would make this super super easy.

Comment: this is a start but its not getting me different values for each CCC group in the index , con2 <-  within(con, indx <- as.numeric(interaction(Interaction_Id,User_Type_cd,  drop=TRUE, lex.order=TRUE)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a sequencing vector that has the same value within contiguous runs of values of the user column. Let's assume this currently unnamed dataframe has the name 'dat':

```
ct <- 1; for( i in seq_along(dat$user)[-1] ) { if (dat$user[i] != dat$user[i-1]) {
                 ct <-c( ct,tail(ct,1)+1)
                 }else{ct <- c(ct, tail(ct,1))} }
> ct
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 5   # this is your "user_block"
```

Then you can use ave() with that as an index to do whatever it is you want, which I *think* is to get the difference of  first and last values of 'timeshift' within runs of 'user' (but not really sure since you took way too many words to say that:

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Sequen_num = 1:8, 
    user = c("A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A"), time_shift = c(1L, 
    15L, 32L, 47L, 65L, 80L, 110L, 120L)), .Names = c("ID", "Sequen_num", 
"user", "time_shift"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

> dat$differ <- ave(dat$time_shift, factor(ct), FUN=function(x) tail(x,1)-head(x,1) )
> dat
  ID Sequen_num user time_shift differ
1  1          1    A          1      0
2  1          2    C         15     32
3  1          3    C         32     32
4  1          4    C         47     32
5  1          5    A         65      0
6  1          6    C         80     30
7  1          7    C        110     30
8  1          8    A        120      0
```

On the other hand it you wanted the cumulative sum:

```
>  dat$cumtime <- ave(dat$time_shift, factor(ct), FUN=cumsum )
> dat
  ID Sequen_num user time_shift differ cumtime
1  1          1    A          1      0       1
2  1          2    C         15     32      15
3  1          3    C         32     32      47
4  1          4    C         47     32      94
5  1          5    A         65      0      65
6  1          6    C         80     30      80
7  1          7    C        110     30     190
8  1          8    A        120      0     120
```

Here is a function that will construct distinct indices for "runs" of either numbers or characters:

```
runcatf <- function(x) cumsum(c(TRUE, x[-length(x)] != x[-1]))
```

Try with:

```
dat$runcat <- ave (dat$tuser, dat$ID,   FUN=runcatf )
```

This will probably work within data.table operations as well. Try

```
dat.tbl[ , runcat := ave(user) , by=c("ID") ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Man you know your stuff. So far that seems to be working fantastically. Wow. I really need to learn R as a whole . So far coming from SAS I am learning Piece wise so its very uphill right now for me. the only thing I noticed is the tails of the last user block get the same value as the head of the next user block for differ, but I am going to work on that

Comment: I am using cbind to join Ct to dat, is that bad form ? It seems to work but I may not fully understand all the caveats

Comment: `cbind`? Should be fine.

Comment: I ended up using this to break it out by Id:     ct <- 1; 
for (j in length(filter$Interaction_Id)  ) { 
 if ( filter$Interaction_Id[i] == filter$Interaction_Id[i-1]) 
{for ( i in seq_along(filter$User_Type_cd)[-1]  ) 
{if ( filter$User_Type_cd[i] != filter$User_Type_cd[i-1]    & ( filter$Interaction_Id[i] == filter$Interaction_Id[i-1])  )   
      {    ct <-c( ct,tail(ct,1)+1) }
      
      
     
     else {    
                     if (filter$Interaction_Id[i] != filter$Interaction_Id[i-1])        {ct <-c( ct,tail(ct,1)+1) }   else 
{  ct <- c(ct, tail(ct,1))}  
                     }} } }

Comment: 2 things: this runs very slow on only 60K rows, so on 40 million it just wouldnt be viable. Second off, it randomly stopped working and now I am getting errors. man.

Comment: I'm wondering if you understand the character of this site? You have two different persons contributing ideas to a question that was ambiguous and didn't include an example that represented the complexity of the problem, and all you have done so far is complain. No upvotes. Why should I bother to post the faster approach I have developed?

Comment: Im not complaining! I am very thankful! Sorry if it came off that way. This is my first post and I am learning the ropes and I cant up vote. I am sorry.

Comment: Still waiting ... I wasn't kidding when I said I had an improved solution, but if I close out this session that has been running for 2 days it  may get lost.

Comment: thanks BondedDust , sorry for such a poorly phrased question and poor responses that didn't help on my end.   I did a very very poor job of setting up the question. What do you need from me when you say still waiting? I cant up-vote it says I need at least a reputation of 15 if thats what you mean.

Comment: Hah. Did not realize there was a threshold you need to cross for upvoting. Posting the function that I think will work if you use with ave and include the 'ID' and 'user' columns as index variables. Would probably work in the data.table answer so if that turns out to be better, tehn please switch the checkmark to Mike's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am probably confused to what you want.  `data.table` might be a place to start though.

```
#Make data
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Sequen_num = 1:8, 
user = c("A", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A"), time_shift = c(1L, 
15L, 32L, 47L, 65L, 80L, 110L, 120L)), .Names = c("ID", "Sequen_num", 
"user", "time_shift"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-8L))

#Calculate running count of A's (or non-C's)
require("data.table")
dat<- data.table(dat)

#Find running cnt of non-C values
dat[,Running.A.Cnt := factor(cumsum(dat$user!="C"))]

#Create a new group variable
dat[user=="C",NewGroup:=.GRP,by=c("user","Running.A.Cnt")]
dat[user!="C",NewGroup:=NA]

#Calculate difference between first and last entry
dat[user=="C",differ:=(time_shift[.N]-time_shift[1]),by=c("NewGroup")]
dat

#     ID Sequen_num user time_shift Running.A.Cnt NewGroup differ
# 1:  1          1    A          1             1       NA     NA
# 2:  1          2    C         15             1        1     32
# 3:  1          3    C         32             1        1     32
# 4:  1          4    C         47             1        1     32
# 5:  1          5    A         65             2       NA     NA
# 6:  1          6    C         80             2        2     30
# 7:  1          7    C        110             2        2     30
# 8:  1          8    A        120             3       NA     NA
```

Comment: Hey Mike, BondedDust pretty much has it nailed, but when moving onto the next ID it carries over the last count into the first instance of the new ID, so its very close. I need to play with it some more.

Comment: Hey Mike thanks , I am going to try that next. the nested loops literally take forever to run and I am pretty sure the data table approach will be much faster. thanks a ton. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: Sure thing.  Let me know how long it takes to run (and how big the data is)!

Comment: the daily files are 400K-500K rows. so monthly and quarterly get large pretty quick

Comment: Hey Mike, This runs instantly-and it works great. and its blazingly fast. thank you so much. I have now decided to spend some time learning the data table package in R. Thanks very much.  the only problem, is this runs into the same problem as the last one, the first C (client) block for the next user ID does the difference in time shift wrong, whereas the nested for loops , it will take the difference from the last client block (say 773 is the time shift) and then the 1 from the next, getting a time shift of -722 instead of what it should be

Comment: I need to figure out a way to have it take into account the user ID as it runs, making sure the last userID matches the current

Comment: this seems to give the breaks that I need at the ID level and still groups properly:     dat[user=="C",NewGroup:=.GRP,by=c("user","ID" ,"Running.A.Cnt")]  --- And its very fast.

Comment: The sample dataset only has 1 ID, so I didn't think to group by it.  Glad it was fairly fast for you!

Comment: thanks mike, sorry. I did a very very poor job of setting up the question.